# Detect actual size of HTML content in the WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

Is there any way to detect the contents height/width in the WebBrowser control?   I'd like to save the contents to an image but only at the size of the actual contents.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can get it from the following property:

```
myWebBrowser.Document.ScrollRectangle.Size;
```

Being a `System.Drawing.Size` object.

Comment: That's not it.  That defaults to 250x250.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I used to to figure out it was available here: browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle using width/height.

Comment: Yeah, I knew the information was available in there somewhere, sorry for the inaccuracy, I'll edit my above post for people searching for similar solutions.

Answer (score 1):

[The document recalculate the layout each time the size of the browser window changes, so it does not really have a fixed size.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/2f8fe772-da32-4933-9122-c1c4688bd4f7)

You can using a Golden section search to find the minimal window size large enough to contain the document, but it is a CPU-intensive task.

Answer (score 0):

loop elements select max height/width. i used this after documentCompleted event

```
    //fit to content  -get size **after documentCompleted**
    var wbAll = webBrowser.Document.All.Cast<HtmlElement>();
    var maxWidth = wbAll.Max(x => Math.Max(x.ClientRectangle.Width, x.ScrollRectangle.Width));
    var maxHeight =wbAll.Max(x => Math.Max(x.ClientRectangle.Height, x.ScrollRectangle.Height));

    webBrowser.Height = maxHeight;
    webBrowser.Width = maxWidth;
```